# C++ Reading an entire file directory

Tags: c++, file, directory, filesystems

I've made a short program that reads a set number of text files and extracts some targeted information out of them. However, this relies on me adding all those text files into the project folder and renaming every single one of them individually to give their names a pattern.

What I'd like to make my code read ALL files in a folder (named by the path there) regardless of the names and regardless of the amount of files in the folder.

I'm a total beginner at programming so I would very much appreciate if all steps were explained as simple as possible so i can learn from this :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: There are many tutorials and articles about how to iterate or enumerate directories and files. on both POSIX (e.g. Linux or macOS) and Windows systems. What have you tried searching for? What have you found? Do you have a specific question, because this isn't really a tutorial site (please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)).

Comment: This may be a place to start: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to utilize `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` in C++17 standard library.
A minimal example:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    for (auto& file : std::filesystem::directory_iterator{ "." })  //loop through the current folder
    {
        std::ifstream fs{ file.path() };    //open the file
        //or because directory_entry is implicit converted to a path, so you can do 
        //std::ifstream fs{ file };
        //... process the file
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need! (probably)
I got an error at "filesystem" in std::filesystem::directory_iterator{ "." } and at the '{'.
"name followed bu "::" must be a class or namespace name", what does that mean?
I'm assuming I can remove the std:: if I'm using "using namespace std;".
Should i write the path to the folder inside the parentheses in file.path()?

Comment: ``{"."}`` shouldn't cause an error, because it is uniform initialization syntax. Make sure you have ``-std=c++17`` flag if you use GCC or ``/std:c++17`` if you use Visual Studio. You can do either way for ``file.path()``, because that's what I just found.

Comment: How do i know if I use the latest version off c++? Im working in visual studio. Downloaded it a last week.
I also didnt really understand what you meant by i can use either way. And whats a uniform initialization syntax?

Comment: @Trålarn'  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019  If you don't understand what I said, just use the explicit std::ifstream fs{file.path()}; I provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace std;
vector<string> list_dir(const char *path) {
vector<string> AllFilesName;
struct dirent *entry;
DIR *dir = opendir(path);

if (dir == NULL) {
   return;
   }

//readdir return a pointer to the entry of a folder (could be any type not only .txt)

while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
   AllFilesName.push_back(entry->d_name);
//push the name of every file
}
   closedir(dir);
return AllFilesName; 
}
string readFile(string name){
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:\\temp\\"+name);//concatenate the name with the directory path
//just replace your folder path with C:\\temp
    while(inFile >> x) {
        //x is the content of the file do whatever you want
    }
    //return the contetn of the text 
}
int main() {
   vector<string> nameOfFiles = list_dir("/home/username/Documents");
   for(int i=0;i<nameOfFiles.size();i++){
       string contentOfTheFile = readFile(nameOfFiles[i]);//read the folder know as you like 
   }
return 0;
}
```